# Select a table or array for each row of a bigger select query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Using Oracle 11g

Suppose we have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    item_id NUMBER(22,0)
);

CREATE TABLE messages (
    item_id NUMBER(22,0),
    message_code NUMBER(22,0)
);
```

where there is one (item) to many (messages) relationship. I want to select all the stuff in a single query to get it into java. Is is possible to write such a query, that it would give me output like:

```
ID         MESSAGE
----------------------------------
1          (100, 105, 201)
2          (100, 105)
```

where MESSAGE column is an array or something like that (not a concatenated string)?

Comment: Why don't you want to use multiple rows per ID?  Once you break out of the relational model it's hard to go back, and you'll end up supporting all kinds of weird queries that are useless in many contexts.

Comment: @jonearles: how can a query break a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on Quassnoi's answer, there is also the `COLLECT` function which will do the same thing as `MULTISET` in the other answer but without the subquery.

```
CREATE TYPE t_message_code AS TABLE OF INTEGER;

WITH    items AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS item_id
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS item_id
        FROM    dual
        ),
        messages AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS item_id, 100 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 AS item_id, 105 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 AS item_id, 201 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS item_id, 100 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS item_id, 15 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        )
SELECT  i.item_id, 
  cast(collect(m.message_code) as t_message_code) as messages_codes
FROM    
  items i
  join messages m on (m.item_id = i.item_id)
group by i.item_id;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use field-level cursors:

```
WITH    items AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS item_id
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS item_id
        FROM    dual
        ),
        messages AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS item_id, 100 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 AS item_id, 105 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 AS item_id, 201 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS item_id, 100 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS item_id, 15 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        )
SELECT  item_id,
        CURSOR
        (
        SELECT  message_code
        FROM    messages m
        WHERE   m.item_id = i.item_id
        )
FROM    items i
```

or create a table type and cast a `MULTISET` of the values to that type:

```
CREATE TYPE t_message_code AS TABLE OF INTEGER

WITH    items AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS item_id
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS item_id
        FROM    dual
        ),
        messages AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS item_id, 100 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 AS item_id, 105 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 AS item_id, 201 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS item_id, 100 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS item_id, 15 AS message_code
        FROM    dual
        )
SELECT  item_id,
        CAST
        (
        MULTISET
        (
        SELECT  message_code
        FROM    messages m
        WHERE   m.item_id = i.item_id
        ) AS t_message_code
        )
FROM    items i
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I used the second variant - with MULTISET and table types - and it worked like a charm. It fitted Java application well, because we have already used table types for passing lists of values to stored procedures. As for the first variant, I tried it in SQLDeveloper and at first it worked, but then I got an error saying I have reached a maximum number of cursors (the table was ~100 rows long).

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: this will give you a string (not you wanted), but I'll left this answer here since this question is asked quite often and not all people yet know about such simple solution

```
  SELECT item_id AS id,
         wm_concat(message_code) AS message
    FROM messages
GROUP BY item_id
```

If you need parentheses around the message ids list you could use concatenation:

```
'(' || wm_concat(message_code) || ')' AS message
```

Comment: This will result in a concatenated string

Comment: @Quassnoi: yep, missed that OP did not want it to be a string :-S thanks for correction...

Comment: To clear why I didn't want a string. My goal is to get all these values in Java. The string needs parsing. The first concern here is that if messages contained not only code, but also text, things would get complicated. The second concern is that in our project we don't use OOP domain model in Java and hence there is no custom conversion/mapping done. We use maps and lists and ideally I would like this array to appear as a list of map. In case of concatenated strings, I would have manually specify which column should be parsed and using which format.

Comment: and wm_concat is undocumented, so use at your own risk.

Comment: In 11.2 you could use listagg which is documented.